# Android Studio: Flexible Layout (Only with XML?)

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've got problems to make my layout flexible.

[image]

If I switch to landscape my buttons inside my gridlayout keep static. And there is a lot of space on the right side of my gridlayout.

[image]

I want to center my gridlayout and make the size of my buttons changeable to any device size.

My XML-Code here (showing only two buttons):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fdai3744.taschenrechnerneu.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="@string/cal_btn_clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="@string/cal_btn_clear_entry" />
</GridLayout>
```

Is it possible only to use XML or should I also use Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***want to center my gridlayout:***

Use:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

in your GridLayout.

***make the size of my buttons changeable to any device size:***
In order to do that, you will have to create multiple values folders in your project so that you can support multiple screens. For example, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, ..ect. There are plenty of resources on how to do that here in Stack.
Hope that helps.